# Hosting Slim Framework Rest API in Windows

Tags: api, slim

I created an api using SLIM framework, but the services are not accessible to public as they are limited to localhost. how to host the services on a realtime server, so that, they can be accessible from anywhere? 
please some one help me

Answer (score 1):

This question requires more detail in order to answer properly.

1. If you are hosting your API on a windows server, then it is likely you have configured some kind of "WAMP" stack, correct? Or maybe serving PHP through IIS? This are important questions because we need to know what port you have bound your web application server to, which leads us to the next question...
2. Where are you hosting the server which is running the application which bound to what port?

Ultimately, a public, external IP will need to be either:

a. NAT'ed to the internal IP of your web server instanced
b. Port-forwarded to the internal IP of the server running your web application

Still, we are making a lot of assumptions here because getting a web application "accessible from anywhere" will require different work depending on your environment.

Here is the most basic example:

You are at home, running this API on your Windows workstation and will like to be able to hit it from a remote location.

1. Ensure Windows firewall allows inbound traffic to the port on which your application is running (probably port 80/HTTP, maybe 443/HTTPS).
2. Log into your ISP's router and configure port-forwarding to ensure inbound traffic on, say, port 80, is routed to the internal IP of the workstation running the API.

That's all there is to it.

Keep in mind that this also assumes that your ISP even allows you to expose your own web server to the internet on port 80 (or 443). Also, since we know nothing about your environment, this is all pure conjecture. Please provide more information you would like a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most traditional way to host Slim Framework, would be through Apache. Install Apache and be sure you have the proper network settings to allow inbound connections, but more information about your setup could be needed for proper guidance.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html

When Apache is installed and working, you need to set Rewrite rules on the URL, information on that can be found on http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/.

Your question on the verge of off topic, it probaly is, but read up on what questions can be asked and not, here on Stackoverflow, hope i could help.